# Equivalent Divisor and Evaluation

Tags: elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I've been reading the "[Pairing for Beginners](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/PairingsForBeginners.pdf)" tutorial from Craig Costello and have been asking myself about the example given in section 3.3 (Weil Reciprocity page 44, example 3.3.2). It states that if $supp(D)~\cap~supp((f)) \neq \emptyset$, then one could find an equivalent divisor $D'$ such that one is allowed to evaluate $f(D')$ (i.e. both divisors have disjoint supports).

In this example, if $D = (P)+(R)+(T) - 3(\mathcal{O})$ ($P, S, T$ are on the same line), then $D \sim D'$ where $D' = (P+U)+(S+U)+(T+U)-3(U)$ ($U$ is a random point over $E(\mathcal{F}_q)$ that does not belong to $supp(f)$). Hence, one can compute $f(D')$ thanks to this equivalent $D'$.

Let $e$ be the Weil Pairing function. I know that if $D  \sim D'$ then $e(D, P) = e(D', P)$ (this can be easily proved thanks to Weil Reciprocity theorem). However, I'm not sure to understand the meaning given to this $f(D')$ evaluation.

What is the relationship between  $f(D)$, $f(D')$ and $f(D'+(g))$ where $g$ is a rational function (note that $D$, $D'$ and $D'+(g)$ belong to the same class) ? Does it actually make sense to evaluate these quantities if they are not used for pairing ?